# Enviar múltiplos valores do checkbox para modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript

Boa noite,

Tenho uma lista de checkbox e preciso enviar para um modal a informação de quais checkbox estão com status 'ckecked'.

Estou usando o código abaixo, mas não estou conseguindo, podem me ajudar por favor?

**form**

`<form id="form">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="disponivel">1</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="disponivel">2</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="disponivel">3</li>
    </ul>
    <button id="salvar"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teste" onclick="obterMarcados();">Enviar</button>
</form>`

**modal**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservados </h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Valor:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.JS**

`<script>
    var botao = document.querySelector('#salvar');
    var form = document.querySelector('#form');

    botao.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#teste').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var numeros = form.disponivel.value;
        var modal = $(this)
        modal.find('.modal-title').text('Reservar Números ' + numeros)
        modal.find('.modal-body input').val(numeros)
        });
    });
</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        $('#teste').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
        })

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mybtn1").click(function() {
                var p=$("#teste #result");
                $(p).html("Disponíveis: ");
                $.each($("input[name='disponivel']:checked"), function() {
                    $(p).html($(p).html() + '<br>' + $(this).val());
                });      
            }); 
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


      <div class="modal fade" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservados </h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Valor:</label>
                  <p id="result"></p>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <form id="form">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="disponivel">1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="disponivel">2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="disponivel">3</li>
        </ul>     
      </form>

      <button  id = "mybtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teste" >Ver disponíveis</button>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Se a intenção é para colocar num **value** de um **input** é como segue.

Obs: os valores foram separados por virgulas para que se possa manipular de forma mais facil posteriormente.

```js
   $('#teste').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
          $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
        })

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#mybtn1").click(function() {
                var numeros="";
             $.each($("input[name='disponivel']:checked"), function() {

                    //sem virgulas retire +"," na linha abaixo
                    numeros +=$(this).val()+",";

                    
                });

                // sem virgulas retire toda a linha abaixo 
                numeros = numeros.substring(0,(numeros.length - 1));

               document.getElementById("recipient-name").value = numeros;
            }); 
        });
```

```html
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


      <div class="modal fade" id="teste" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Reservados </h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Valor:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <form id="form">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="disponivel">1</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="disponivel">2</li>
            <li><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="disponivel">3</li>
        </ul>     
      </form>

      <button  id = "mybtn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#teste" >Enviar para modal</button>
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```